# why the chatbubble arrow is not aligining properly on old browser

Tags: html, css

I am currently trying to create an chat bubble arrow which works on all recent browser but on xullrunner it fails and does not comes properly

**CSS:**

```
.speech-wrapper{
  padding: 5px 10px;
  }
.chatbox {
  padding: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-top:3px;   
  background: #c7edfc;
  color: #000;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 4px;  
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  hyphens: auto;
}
.timestamp{
        font-size: 11px;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 8px;
        right: 10px;
        text-transform: uppercase; color: #999
      }
/* speech bubble 13 */
      .name{
        font-weight: 600;
        font-size: 12px;
        margin: 0 0 4px;
        color: #3498db;
      }
        .bubble-arrow {
      position: absolute;
      width: 0;
      bottom:42px;
      left: -19px;
      height: 0;

    }

    .bubble-arrow:after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      border: 0 solid transparent;
      border-top: 9px solid #c7edfc;
      border-radius: 0 20px 0;
      width: 15px;
      height: 30px;
      transform:rotate(145deg);

    }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="speech-wrapper"><div class="chatbox"><div><p class="name">Apple TestUser1</p>Hi<span class="timestamp">10:20 pm</span>
  <div class="bubble-arrow"></div>
  </div></div>
```

I run the above code got output in all recent bowser as imag shown below [image]

But on xullrunner the transform seems to fail and it gives me below output

[image]

here the arrow is not rotated correctly and gives me a wrong output

**EDIT**
After trying out solution suggested by answer I am getting  a line on arrow as below image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this code here:**

```css
.speech-wrapper{
  padding: 5px 10px;
  }
.chatbox {
  padding: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-top:3px;   
  background: #c7edfc;
  color: #000;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 4px;  
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  hyphens: auto;
}
.timestamp{
        font-size: 11px;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 8px;
        right: 10px;
        text-transform: uppercase; color: #999
      }
/* speech bubble 13 */
      .name{
        font-weight: 600;
        font-size: 12px;
        margin: 0 0 4px;
        color: #3498db;
      }
        .bubble-arrow {
      position: absolute;
      width: 0;
      bottom:42px;
      left: -19px;
      height: 0;

    }

    .bubble-arrow:after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      left: 2px;
      border: 9px solid transparent;
      border-color: transparent  #c7edfc transparent transparent;
 

    }
```

```html
<div class="speech-wrapper"><div class="chatbox"><div><p class="name">Apple TestUser1</p>Hi<span class="timestamp">10:20 pm</span>
  <div class="bubble-arrow"></div>
  </div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Now the Line comes In my browser check the edited image And how to have the bubble from opposite side .Othere one I was rotating and fixing the position

Comment: if you needed reverse site arrow then add a class in parent and edit same code

Comment: Ohk But did you see my edited code the arrow is not smooth I can see some line I tried using       z-index:-1;

Comment: I don't know what's you wrong, but my code is work fine, can you see again

Comment: Yeah checked it The line is visible at the end And it hapens only on old browser like xulrunner Old mozzila

Comment: Old browser maybe added some default value, you can remove default value